# Cannot get the width of an absolute position element with jquery

Tags: jquery, width, absolute

Please help me, i cannot get the width of an absolute position element with jquery. My element uses: `height: 100%` and `width: auto` via CSS.

I use `$(element).width()` but obtain a 0.
Here is an example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LVjBvz

I need the element take the width of the inside image. This image has 4000x800px but i use width:100% and height:auto in css to have the image in fullscreen

Comment: Please provide a working example.

Comment: Your element may have a width of 0.  Post the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is executing before the image has a change to fully load. Use the `$(window).load(` to wait for it to complete:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    var contimg;
    contimg = $('#cont_img');
    ancho = contimg.width();
    alert(ancho);
})
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/8unbtrrj/)**

Ref: https://api.jquery.com/load-event/ and https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

> The load event is sent to an element when it and all sub-elements have
>   been completely loaded. This event can be sent to any element
>   associated with a URL: images, scripts, frames, iframes, and the
>   window object.

Comment: Thank you. This solved my issue quickly and makes sense with an absolutely positioned element.